# Possible to customize the Android Bluetooth pairing request notification?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to create an Android App that makes it very clear and simple for a user to connect to a bluetooth device to collect some data.

Ideally, I'd like to eliminate the pairing request notification and have the app auto-pair to the device but not sure if this is possible. If not, is it possible to customize the pairing request notification?  It currently says "To pair with XXX confirm it is showing the passkey..."  Can that be customized to be more user friendly?

Is there anyway to bypass this?

Thanks

Comment: what would you suggest to make it user friendly ? I think the answer is probably no because shooing passkey will be required to meet security requirements on the device.

Comment: What protocol are you using in Bluetooth, RFComm?  If so there is a way.  Also will the phone be rooted?

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe it's possible to avoid pairing.. My opinion is that is mandatory there for security reasons...